# Wordpress using custom single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom single page `single-ENG.php`. I want to use this page for posts with a taxonomy `language=>english`. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you please confirm something? Are you wishing to use the template `single-ENG.php` to show the contents of one single post, instead of `single.php`, where your above criteria are met (correct)? Or are you wishing to show a list of posts that meet you above criteria on a page (incorrect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but I think you need to take a look at the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) first.

There are a few issues with your approach:

You shouldn't name your Custom Page Templates 'single-xxxx.php'. The 'single' prefix is used for a Single Post view. This could confuse Wordpress and cause it to only load the template when you are viewing a Single Post of Post Type 'ENG' (which probably doesn't exist in your theme).

Using Pages as a Shell for any kind of Post content is not advised. The reason for this is that you're essentially circumventing the existing tools Wordpress provides in order to force it to do something it can already do using its own built-in defaults.

Instead of creating a whole new Page Object to house your Posts of a given Taxonomy, why not just create a taxonomy-language-english.php file, and set up its navigation in your theme's Menu (Dashboard->Appearance->Menus)?

Provided you've actually [Registered your Language Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), Wordpress will automatically recognize the new Taxonomy template and query all appropriate data in its default loop.

This details how you can query your Posts using two methods. The first is the one I advise using, provided you change your structure to fit as an exercise in good practice. The second is your approach by applying a Custom Template to a given Page. I've taken the liberty using a new file name to avoid confusing Wordpress:

**Using taxonomy-language-english.php**

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    echo get_the_title().'<br/>'; //Output titles of queried posts
endwhile;
else :
    echo 'No posts were found'; //No posts were found
endif;
?>
```

**Using pagelang-english.php**

```
<?php
/**
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage MyWordpressThemeName
* Template Name: Single English
*/
$args = array('tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'language',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'english'
    )
));
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    echo get_the_title().'<br/>'; //Output titles of queried posts
endwhile;
else :
    echo 'No posts were found'; //No posts were found
endif;
?>
```

This should be enough to get you started. Good luck.

Comment: I not understand what to do in `Dashboard->Appearance->Menus` create new menu ?

Comment: Yes. Create a new menu, and then - once you're done populating it - select that menu in one of the dropdowns on the top-left. Be sure to also enable the options you need by click Screen Options in the upper right-hand corner of the screen. It's easy to miss.

Comment: Custom links URL : there is path to taxonomy-language-english.php ?

Comment: You might want to open a new question for help with the Menu system, and properly registering a Language TAXONOMY (not Category). There's too much to go over in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. The below code assumes that your Custom Taxonomy is called `language` and the Term to check for has the slug `english` (obviously change as required). Put this code in your `functions.php` file.

```
/**
 * Select a custom single template
 *
 * @param required string $single The path to the single template
 * @return string $single The updated path to the required single template
 */
function my_single_template($single){

    global $wp_query, $post;

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'language');

    if(!empty($terms)) : foreach($terms as $term) :

            if($term->slug === 'english') :
                $single = sprintf('%1$s/single-ENG.php', TEMPLATEPATH); 
            endif

        endforeach;
    endif;

    return $single;

}
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');
```

**EDIT**

Having read the answer provided by @maiorano84, I agree that this isn't the best way of doing it. There are few circumstances I can think of where this technique should be used, but the fact WP have added the filter shows that they understand there may be the need, so you should be safe to use it.

Comment: $single is `site.net/single.php` ?

Comment: `$single` is the path to your single-template -`root/wp-content/themes/whatever-theme/single.php`. Your template `single-ENG.php` should go in the same folder.

Comment: Ok but what will hap when someone will go not from page.php but directly by post url ?

Comment: I don't understand where `page.php` comes in to it? My understanding of your question - You have an index of single posts, and when the user clicks to view one, if that post contains the Term 'languate->english`, the template `single-ENG.php` is used to display the post. If not, `single.php` is used as normal.

Comment: ok, but if user not clink on link but write site/post-name when your method will not work

Comment: Should do, yes. What is your Permalink structure (`Settings->Permalinks` in the admin)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19540/discussion-between-tomas-lietuva-and-david-gard)